# Printing window remains open in new tab while printing a div using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using below code to print a div using jQuery.

I am opening a new tab(window) in browser to print that.

Its working fine, but printing window(tab) still remains open in new tab which supposed to be closed on "Cancel button".

```
function printDiv(id) {
var html = "";

$('link').each(function () { 
    if ($(this).attr('rel').indexOf('stylesheet') != -1) { 
        html += '<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + $(this).attr("href") + '" />';
    }
});
html += '<body onload="window.focus(); window.print()">' + $("#" + id).html() + '</body>';
var w = window.open();   
if (w) { w.document.write(html); w.document.close() } 
}
```